# how do I bake bone rotations driven by a bone constraint?

Tags: animation, constraints, drivers, baking

I am just working on a webGL project. Therefore I animated a train in Blender using a bone constraint to make the train follow a bezier curve. I also want to make the bones I created for the wheels to rotate dependent on
the "follow Path" offset_factor.

This works pretty well so far, but in order to make this work in webGL i want to bake my animations.

So, if I bake the animation the train follows the path perfectly, but the driven bone rotation for the wheels is missing. Propapbly, because the constraint "Follow Path" isn't present anymore.

My question is: Is there a way to bake driven properties to animations? And how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!